# Stackable and recognizable Lego

Tags: arduino

I want to create small blocks (lego 2x2 bricks) that contain a small circuit that allows them to be recognized when stacked.

I have about 25 different colors. Of each color, I have 10 blocks. Each block contains a small circuit (slightly different per color) that has X connectors at the bottom (let's call that input) and X connectors at the top (let's call that output). Then I have a base plate that also has X 'output' connectors. When stacking those blocks in a small tower on the base plate, the input connectors of each block, connect with the output connectors of the block below it, of with the base plate. For the sake of the example, let's limit the tower height to 10 blocks.

What I want to do is connecting some device to the base plate (Arduino, for example) and in that device I want to be able to tell which colors of blocks are in the tower and how many of each color.

Is this even possible? And how?

Comment: Sounds like a job for daisy-chained shift-registers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thought is a unique identity for each block with a chip like [DS2401](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/2903) , then the data can be read using one wire protocol.

[Relevant reading](http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/178) , it's solution 1A